# Llamada a una politica y siempreme retorna "false" con LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-7, model

Tengo muchas politicas en mi proyecto pero una de ellas no me funciona

```
public function pass(User $user, Cartera $cartera){
    return $user->id === $cartera->users_id;
}
```

Ya he hecho de todo hasta la he puesto a retornar un TRUE pero es como si mi controlador no la encontrara. Asi la llamo en mi Controlador:

```
$cartera = Cartera::where('users_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $this->authorize('pass', $cartera);
```

y aun me sigue diciendo acceso no autorizado

este es mi AuthServiceProviders

```
protected $Policies = [ 
    Cartera::class => CarteraPolicy::class
];
```

Comment: ¿Esta policy que da problemas si la registraste en el *AuthServiceProvider*?

Comment: Si la registre en mi AuthServiceProvider, pero solo me falla cuando la llamo desde el controlador que le pertenece

Comment: Cuidado aqui tienes mal escrita la propiedad `protected $Policies` va todo en minúscula

Comment: Lo corregi y nada, no se que es lo que pasa porque en algnos controladores me funciona y en otros no